# c# Time Display AM PM

Tags: c#

I know we can do the following to show AM PM for a Time.

```
    String.Format("{0:t}", dt);  // "4:05 PM"
```

What if I want to show A for AM and P for PM. Is there a format for that?

Comment: Use the format and then a substring without the last letter?

Comment: In the above sample code, "{0:t}" actually shows the desired result.
"{0:tt}" would show "AM" or "PM".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution would be to use the **[System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx)** class which allows you to specify how you want your AM/PM to be formatted:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo timeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
timeFormat.ShortTimePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
timeFormat.AMDesignator = "A";
timeFormat.PMDesignator = "P";

// Both of these are the same:
string a = DateTime.Now.ToString("t", timeFormat);
string b = String.Format(timeFormat, "{0:t}", DateTime.Now);
```

You can do completely custom stuff with it:

```
timeFormat.AMDesignator = "cookies";
timeFormat.PMDesignator = "bagels";
```

Example output for 4:05 PM:

```
4:05 bagels
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
String.Format("{0:h:mm t}", DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 2):

use "t":

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("date1 = {0:hh:mm:ss.F t}", DateTime.Now);
// date1 = 12:49:35.4 A
```

(more details on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#tSpecifier)

Comment: I would roll-back the edit ...although it duplicated the sample in the link, you supplied the gist of the answer without making me go look at it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you could probably use ? String.Format().IndexOf("AM") > 0 ? "A" : "P"

Comment: Way too difficult to manage and not as culture-friendly as the example @the_joric demonstrates.